# Numbers in Arabic Netspeak

Tags: writing-systems, arabic

I came across [this list](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeagueEsports/comments/vz41u5/mena_player_name_pronounciations/) of numbers to represent sounds in Arabic netspeak:

> 2 is A
>
> 3 is a heavy (so heavy) A, sure you can't even pronounce it but you could replace with a regular A, no one would care
>
> 4 is basically (th) like the word (tho).
>
> 5 is k and h together it's hard to pronounce so you could just pronounce with a regular k
>
> 6 is kind of between hard T and hard D, a difficult letter for non-Arabic speakers, but you can just pronounce it as a T.
>
> 7 is the most common number that ME players use, it pronounces heavy H but you can pronounce it with a regular h
>
> 8 is basically (g) like in the word (go).
>
> 9 is a heavy S, but you can pronounce it with a regular s

How do the numbers relate to the Arabic alphabet? Is there a specific reason that the number matches the sound/letter?

Curious to see how all of this works.

Comment: The shapes of the numbers resemble the shapes of the Arabic letters the numbers stand for. You can start from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_chat_alphabet

Comment: The word "heavy" is doing a lot of heavy lifting here, but the majority of the cases are really referring to pharyngealisation or the emphatic series.

Answer (score 6):

These numbers are chosen to resemble various Arabic letters that don't have Latin equivalents.

- 2 is ء
- 3 is ع‎
- 5 is خ
- 6 is ط‎
- 7 is ح‎
- 9 is ص‎

You can see that the number vaguely resembles the shape of the Arabic letter.

I'm not sure which letters they're describing for 4 and 8; there are multiple Arabic letters that could fit that description, and none of them look especially like the number.

Comment: The usage of 4 is typically used for "ش", but it's not used very much.

Comment: 8 here is probably ق. They're probably describing a variety of Arabic that has undergone the /q/ > /g/ sound change.